# What is the concrete purpose of reverting migrations in Django, and is it safe to work without?

Tags: django, migration, database-migration

In our Django project, we already generally implemented the `reverse_func` in order to be able to roll-back migrations.

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = []

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(forwards_func, reverse_func),
    ]
```

We do it because some team member did it with previous projects, but we never really questioned the need for that.

However with the time, it seems that we never use the rollback mechanism.

Our DB is a volume of a Docker container. 
When we switch on a different branch, we generally replace the volume with a precedent `dev` version, so that we reapply only the latest migrations.

My question is therefore: *Did we mistunderstood the purpose of the `reverse_func`* ? 
- What is the purpose for it in dev ?
- What is the purpose for it in prod ?

And is it safe to work without them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in development environment `reverse_func`  is not very important, If something goes wrong you can simply drop the whole db and recreate it again

but for production environment it will help you return db back to a working state after a buggy release

after running `forwards_func` in production env you may change your db and may find out it was a bad change and your site doesn't work properly any more.
note that there might be some new data in your db so if you use backup you might lose these data

in given scenario having a `reverse_func` can be very helpful, your `reverse_func` will return db to previous working state and you can simply redeploy previous version of your software

note that sometimes `reverse_func` can be an empty function. it's just to tell django that this migration is reversible

you don't always use a `reverse_func` but if something goes wrong (even once a year) you can see the importance of writing it

Comment: Thanks aliva for this answer. Also instead of reverting, a BUGFIX with a new migration can be added to the code and provide the same functionality I presume.

Comment: but it takes more time, and you need to revert back fast. also maybe you just want to return to 5 migrations before that custom migration and without reverse function you can't (django throws and error). so don't be lazy and always write on. It helped in some disasters

Comment: Not really a question of laziness, but rather having a critical mind on what we are doing.